# Java : Byte-array uses more than 50% memory for webapp

Tags: java, arrays, spring, tomcat, architecture

I am working on a Spring-MVC based application which is deployed on Apache tomcat on Debian Wheezy 64 bit, Java-8 X64. When I started profiling, I noticed that byte-array is getting used a lot. 
Is that normal??

Secondly, I have set some options for GC, mentioned below. Based upon that, I see the Heap graph as you can see in screenshot. What I fail to understand is, how to interpret this graph? Should it have spikes, should it be more like a plateau, etc.

Configuration in catalina.sh:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=port_number -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true 
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

Screenshot of VisualVM profiling tool :

[image: Profiling tool heap data]

And here is the byte-array consumption :

[image]

I hope my question is clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Large `byte[]`s in memory is often a result of loading lots of things from disk into memory, particularly images.

Comment: @ControlAltDel : We have lot of temporary objects, but none which are loaded into memory. One thing we have is Cometd, which is Push-notification or push messages framework.